# How do you build an End portal in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In creative mode, how can you build an End portal in the Nether?

Placing End portal frames in the usual configuration and putting eyes of Ender in them doesn't have any result.  The frames and eyes are there, but no portal forms.

Comment: What I saw some of the people on youtube do is that they break the end portal blocks, replace them and put the 'eye' in. It works sometimes on the 4th or 5th time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they only work in the overworld because:

- I've tried and also failed.
- Since they only spawn naturally in the overworld, they only work in the overworld.

Note on B: I do not count the exit portal in the end as an actual end portal.

Comment: I've investigated the world data and found that the exit portal is actually made of identical blocks to the entrance portal, so I disagree with your note. However, that does make it reasonable that, since it swaps you between End/Overworld, it wouldn't make sense in the Nether. (Don't know what would happen if you copied a portal in.)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you must build the portal a certain way.  Taken from the Minecraft wiki:

> Upon placing an Eye of Ender in every End Portal Frame block of a
>   specific portal, the portal activates, creating 9 End Portal blocks
>   inside the frame, and allowing the player to access The End. In
>   creative mode the player can copy the end portal frame by pressing the
>   scroll-wheel on their mouse but the portal will only appear if the
>   **last eye inserted is facing inward** s (the player stands inside the ring
>   to place the final eye). The eyes can not be removed from the portal
>   blocks.

Note the instructions, you must build the portal that way, or your "portal" to the end will never be created.

Also, you cannot build portals to the end within the nether, but only in the overworld.    You can place end portals (via TMI) in the nether, but TMi is a thirdperson mod.

Comment: That's what I read too, but either A) it isn't having any effect, or B) I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @joe updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not impossible.

Notch intended for end portals to be discovered by exploring underground in the overworld. He saw no reason to update the game physics and allow end portals in the nether because the only way to get them in is through creative! In conclusion I would just like to say that it would be very hard to create one. You might have to edit game configs or other things like that (I know thats not what you meant, I'm just being informative). Another way to do it is download a third party program such as McEdit (http://www.mcedit.net/), using the replace tool you can update the blocks and change them to end portals. If there is a block update next to the portals they will disappear. I hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to build an end portal in the nether, as I have done it myself once. 
Pretty easy to build in creative as well. You have to be in the center where you will be placing the end portal frames. each side will have 3 end portal frames and they will be facing inwards to you. Then place the eyes facing inwards towards yourself. On the last one, you may want to fly up to a little as it will turn on the portal.

Pretty easy and simple.